# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/params/BasicHttpParams;

Tags: android, http

I have Upgraded the Android application from 26 to 28 SDK.

It works well in 23 - 27 version.

But the new version will crash in SDK 28.

this is the exception stack:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/params/BasicHttpParams;
    at com.deepnet.andmob5.util.UtilsYang.getNewHttpClient(UtilsYang.java:163)
    at com.deepnet.andmob5.util.UtilsYang.makeRequest(UtilsYang.java:103)
    at com.deepnet.andmob5.util.UtilsYang.sendHTTPPost(UtilsYang.java:426)
    at com.deepnet.andmob5.threads.MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(MyAsyncTask.java:52)
    at com.deepnet.andmob5.threads.MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(MyAsyncTask.java:22)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.deepnet.andmob5-lZYwyb5I5Tn71C5uAAbAOA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.deepnet.andmob5-lZYwyb5I5Tn71C5uAAbAOA==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.deepnet.andmob5-lZYwyb5I5Tn71C5uAAbAOA==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
```

Please help me.

Comment: Make sure that the lilbrary org/apache/http(/params/BasicHttpParams) is included. It may be no longer/not availabe in your version. Or you just need to change the version of the library in your build.gradle file.

Could you provide your build.gradle file of your module?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using the Apache HTTP client, add the following in AndroidManifest.xml:
 [refer this](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#apache-p)

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following line in your *module's **build.gradle***:

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

And don't forget to upgrade the **minSdkVersion** to **23** as it's indicated in the following link:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#apache-p